# Designing database job monitoring

Tags: design, database, database-design, oracle, monitoring

I have several Oracle database where my in-house applications are running. Those applications use both `dba_jobs` and `dba_scheduler_jobs`.

I want to write monitoring function: `check_my_jobs` which will be called periodically by Nagios to check if everything is OK with my jobs. *(Are they running? Is it Broken? Is next_run_date delayed? and so on)*

#### Solutions:

Due to the fact that I have to monitor jobs on different databases, there is two way of implementing the solution:

1. Create monitoring function and configuration tables only on one database which will check jobs on every database using the Database link.

   *pros:* Centralized functionality, easy to maintain.
   *cons:* I have to make a check using the Database link.
2. Create monitoring function and configuration tables in every database where I want to check jobs.

   *pros:* I don't have to use DB link
   *cons:* Duplicated monitoring code on every database

**Which solution is better?**

Comment: Is there anything wrong with database links in your particular environment?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's one right answer here - but there are a few considerations you don't mention above:

- Reliability - Your DB link solution creates a single point of failure (or more accurately an additional one).  Since the point of this is monitoring, that doesn't seem ideal.
- Credential storage - You'll need to store credentials for the connection.  In the DB link case these are stored in the DB link (which is pretty secure if you create it from a privileged account).  You should make sure you have a secure credential storage solution for the other case.  You'll also want to evaluate overhead when the credentials are rotated.
- Performance - DB links tend to be a bit chatty - not ideal for complex interactions over wide area networks
- Encapsulation - From a security point of view, you should think about least privileges, and about encapsulating the function as encapsulated PL/SQL functions.  In 12c you can assign roles to those PL/SQL functions that aren't generally assigned to the user.  That encapsulation / least privs model would require having the code on each database.

The reliability argument would make me lean towards the distributed model

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the latter.
Monitor each database *separately*, with CheckMK acting as the coordinating "hub".

If you centralise the monitoring through *one database*, what happens when that one database *goes down*?
Answer: It takes **all** of your monitoring with it!

Sadly, we do not live in an Ideal World, where everything is "always on".
Stuff happens and, when it does, a distributed monitoring scheme will cope far better than one that relies on any one part of the system always being available.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just check with simple SQL query if specific results come back?

Like:

Select data from table @ db1, and see if results come back, if not Nagios check will fail.